# Unexpected output in codeacademy example

Tags: javascript

I only expected "50" to print out, yet "50", "25", "50" were printed out. Why?
Actual code:

```
var orangeCost = function(price) {
  console.log(price*5);
}
orangeCost(10);
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like a glitch, given you didn't input `10`, `5`, then `10` again. The console saves previous values

Comment: Maybe those were the results of previous function calls...

Comment: You can see the real result in browser console. Try that.

Answer (score 0):

If that's the very first time you ran the code then yes that's an error with code academy. I'd try clearing the console(don't know if that's possible) and run it again.